# Why this HTTPGET method in Controller can work？

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, http

I'm learning ASP.NET CORE 6 with MS official website below：
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Then I found a instruction said "There's no [HttpPost] overload of the Index method as you might expect. You don't need it, because the method isn't changing the state of the app, just filtering data." and I'm confused with it.

the following code is the sample from teaching page, a form tag without method atrribute, so  I think it should be "post" as the default.

```
<form asp-action="index">  
    Search: <input type="text" name="searchText" />
    <input type="submit" value="GO" class="btn btn-secondary" />
</form>
```

And the following action method without [HTTPXXX] attribute should be [HTTPGET] as the default, right?

```
// GET: Movies
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchText)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
    {
        var result = _context.Movie.Where(m=>m.Title!.Contains(searchText));
        return View(await result.ToListAsync());
    }
      return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
}
```

So the question is why I ask a request with POST method, but it still can lead to a GET action method?

Comment: Do you have only one `Index action` on your contoller? Whats your controller name?

Comment: I followed the tutorial building a MoviesController and only one Index() action in it indeed.

Comment: Could you please include your full `controller code` from first to last

Comment: Hows your `app.MapControllerRoute` looks like in `program.cs`?

Comment: Hello, is there anything else that I can assist you on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to HTML specification default value for form.method attributge is 'get'. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/method. That's why it works with GET action, as if you specified `<form asp-action="index" method="get">`

Answer (score 1):

> And the following action method without [HTTPXXX] attribute should be
> [HTTPGET] as the default, right?

Well, if you don't define your from `submit method attribute` by default it will authometically generate `method type` as `post` like this `method="post"`. If you could inspect you can see as below:

[image]

> So the question is why I ask a request with POST method, but it still
> can lead to a GET action method?

Yes you are right. In that case, either you have to define as `method="get"` or you can define and controller and action together. Like this

```
<form asp-action="index" asp-controller="YourController">
```

Or

```
 <form asp-action="index" method="get">
```

**Note:** In official document they used [`asp-controller="Movies"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0) however, you haven't use it in your code which created the issue.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Using `method attribute` `method="get"` is more suitable to resolve your issue other than in browser compiler autometically generate `post` by default.

Comment: You are welcome, does my answer, resolve your issue?

Comment: Actually I have another question about [HTTPXXX] attribute of Action Method.
I found that it can avoid my question happened when I use [HTTPGET] attribute definitely in Index() action.
Does it mean when I didn't decorate [HTTPXXX] attribute clearly and no other same name Action Method exists, it could be called by a POST request?

Comment: Yes right you are, same overload is not accepted and if you don't define `method=""` in your `view` then it will invoke `post method` as said earlier if you don't declare, compiler will generate  as `method="post"` and the request will hit to the `POST mothod` action. Hope its clear to you.

Comment: So your issue can be resolved in 3 ways, by writting `method="get"` or `<form asp-action="index" asp-controller="YourController">` or ` [HTTPGET]` on top your action, both will resolve the issue.